# what is this code doing can not understand it

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to figure out what a query is doing and I just do not understand why it would join its self to its self on multiple occassions highlighted bit is the piece i am talking about?

its the part that starts with the [SupplyStatusUpdated] = COALESCE( gas supply and gas supply history

```
                        USE [CRM];

        SELECT  gs.GasSupplyID, 
                [Account ID] = acc.AccountID,
                [GMSReference] = cast(gms.SiteRefNum as varchar),
                [AccountNumber] = cast(gms.AccountNum as varchar), 
                [Organisation Name] = prf.[Name] ,
                con.DeclaredDate, 
                [Contract Date] = CAST(con.ContractDate AS DATE),
                [Contract Version] = cv.Name,
                [Contract Status] = cs.Name,
                loa.ContractEndDate [LOA CED],
                gs.CurrentSupplierEndDate [PrevSupplierEndDate],
                loa.ContractEndDate,
                con.StartDate,
                [Supply Status] = gss.Name,
                [SupplyStatusUpdated] = COALESCE(
                                                    (   
                                                        SELECT TOP 1 MAX(gsh2.CreatedDate)
                                                        FROM GasSupply gs2 
                                                            INNER JOIN GasSupplyHistory gsh2 
                                                                ON gsh2.GasSupplyFK = gs2.GasSupplyID
                                                        WHERE gsh2.EventFK = 2 
                                                        AND gsh2.Notes LIKE '%Gas Supply Status (%'
                                                        AND gsh2.GasSupplyFK = gs.GasSupplyID
                                                        GROUP BY gsh2.GasSupplyFK
                                                    ),
                                                    (
                                                        SELECT TOP 1 MAX(gsh3.CreatedDate)
                                                        FROM GasSupplyHistory gsh3 
                                                            INNER JOIN  (
                                                                            SELECT gsh4.GasSupplyFK, MAX(gsh4.EventFK) AS [MaxEvent]
                                                                            FROM GasSupplyHistory gsh4
                                                                            WHERE gsh4.GasSupplyFK = gs.GasSupplyID
                                                                            GROUP BY gsh4.GasSupplyFK
                                                                            HAVING MAX(gsh4.EventFK) = 1
                                                                        ) dt 
                                                                ON dt.GasSupplyFK = gsh3.GasSupplyFK
                                                    )
                                                ),
                [EAC] = gs.EstimatedAnnualConsumption,
                [PreviousSupplier] = r.name,
                [Branch] = b.name,
                [LeadSource] = ls.name,
                gs.UnitPrice,
                gs.StandingCharge,
                gs.WholesalePrice,
                COALESCE(deal.weeknumber,DATEPART(ISOWK, con.[ContractDate])) AS [Week]
        FROM    acc.Account acc
            INNER JOIN [Profile] prf    
                ON acc.ProfileFK = prf.ProfileID
            INNER JOIN [Contract] con       
                ON acc.AccountID = con.AccountFK
            INNER JOIN [loacontract] lo
                ON lo.ContractFK = con.ContractID
            LEFT join [LeadSource] ls
                ON ls.LeadSourceID = con.LeadSourceFK
            INNER JOIN [ContractStatus] cs
                ON cs.ContractStatusID = con.ContractStatusFK 
            INNER JOIN [ContractVersion] cv
                ON cv.ContractVersionID = con.ContractVersionFK 
            INNER JOIN GasSupply gs
                ON gs.ContractFK = con.ContractID
            INNER JOIN GasSupplyStatus gss
                ON gss.GasSupplyStatusID = gs.GasSupplyStatusFK 
            LEFT JOIN Deal deal
                ON deal.ContractFK = con.ContractID
            OUTER APPLY GetGMSReferenceNumbers(con.ContractID) gms
            LEFT JOIN Branch b
                ON b.BranchID = deal.BranchFK
            LEFT JOIN DealBroker bro
                ON  bro.DealFK = deal.DealID
                AND bro.BrokerTypeFK = 36
            LEFT JOIN Person p
                ON p.PersonID = bro.EmployeeFK
            LEFT JOIN Reseller r
                ON r.ResellerID = gs.ResellerFK
            LEFT JOIN   (
                            SELECT  l.contractfk,
                                    MIN(l.contractenddate)[ContractEndDate]
                            FROM    CRM.[contract].LOAContract l
                            GROUP BY l.ContractFK       
                        ) loa
                ON loa.ContractFK = con.ContractID

        WHERE acc.AccountID not in  (
                                        select AccountFK 
                                        from AccountOption 
                                        where OptionFK=9
                                    )
        AND  cast(gms.SiteRefNum as varchar) IS NULL
```

Comment: Just read up on SQL Self Joins: [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm)

Comment: i did and made no sense thats why i asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE(Something, SomethingElse)` says if the first argument is NULL, return the second argument (note that you can have more than 2 args and it'll just keep going down the list).

As such it's running the first sub-query, and if the result is NULL, returning the result of the second query. Why exactly is your business logic, which we can't answer :-)

([MSDN link on Coalesce](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx))

Comment: brilliant thank you a very comprenhensive answer and it makes sense why he would be doing this in his query

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` returns the first non-null value it finds, so if the `GasSupply` query returns a result it will use that: if that returns null it will see if the `GasSupplyHistory` query returns a result, and if so use that. If both queries return null then `SupplyStatusUpdated` will be null.

Comment: Thank you for your very spersific answer this along with the other comment has given me a better understanding of why and what he is doing in his query thank you

Answer (score 0):

It joins to itself to get historical records from the same source as where it gets the current record.

Representation of historical data is is one common reason for using a BigData/NoSQL database instead of a SQL/Relational database.